# Cant connect to postgresql with docker-compose

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am facing the problem the host is not found or an error connecting to this hosting

I have tried many different options but have not found a solution to the problem.

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  backend:
    image: webapiwithdockerpostgre
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApiWithDockerPostgre/Dockerfile

  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 5432:5432
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: admin
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: superpassworddocker
        POSGRES_DB: TestDb
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/


volumes:
    database-data:
    pgadmin:
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApiWithDockerPostgre/WebApiWithDockerPostgre.csproj", "WebApiWithDockerPostgre/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApiWithDockerPostgre/WebApiWithDockerPostgre.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApiWithDockerPostgre"
RUN dotnet build "WebApiWithDockerPostgre.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApiWithDockerPostgre.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApiWithDockerPostgre.dll"]
```

Connection string -

```
"Host=database;Database=DbTest;Username=admin;Password=superpassworddocker;Port=5432"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, just change `Host=database` in the connection string to `Host=host.docker.internal` and it works fine

Comment: Incredible, many thanks!

Comment: no problem. i have another solution down here in comments

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you setup your database in the compose file like this

```yaml
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

The host is `localhost` for your machine (if you are debugging for example) and for the application, (like an api in the same compose file), the host will be the name of the service (in this case `db`).

```json
"Host=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=mypassword;Database=postgres;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the database name be `TestDb` instead of `DbTest` in your connection string?

Comment: still doenst work

Comment: another typo. should be `POSTGRES_DB` not `POSGRES_DB`. See the [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Comment: I have a solution down here

Comment: host.docker.internal is your host ip address. It works because you published 5432 port at `database` service.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links said when using the default network config, any service MUST be able to reach any other service at that service’s name. Therefore, using `database` as the hostname isn't a problem. I do try to bring up the containers with your compose yml by replacing the backend with ubuntu. Installing postgresql-client on it and I am able to connect to the db with `psql` after fixing those typo.

Comment: Hello, i have found a solution today. My problem was that port 5432 is busy, after installing PostgreSQL listened to it.

I changed the port mapping to "5438:5432" and everything works. I can connect by image name in docker-compose